# What should be the optimal way to find the average of a large number of integers?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, optimization

Each of the integers can be as large as the size of an integer itself (Java int-32 bits), so storing the sum of the integer numbers in an integer variable isn't an option.
I'm afraid using Java BigInts might affect the performance badly.

Right now I'm trying divide and conquer while using *long* to store the sum.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: How about storing the sum in a floating point number?  The average will be a floating point number anyway.

Comment: Do you know the number of integers in advance?

Comment: Maverick, please see my answer.  Everyone is suggesting using a bigger data type, I am suggesting using a new calculation of your average.

Comment: @Justin: I think the majority of the answers are to use bigger data types and see if it's "fast enough" then ask the question of how to make it faster.

Comment: @sven: I guess floating point will be much slower.
@biziclop: Yes, say all the integers (consider of the order of million of numbers) are stored in text file from which I'm reading.

Comment: @Justin: your answer is also saying to use a bigger data type for the sum - you use "double" when you multiply `currentAverage * currentCount`, and ignoring floating point inaccuracy the result of that multiplication is exactly the same value that everyone else is storing in a `long` or `BigInteger` running total. You just do a lot of unnecessary division along the way.

Comment: @Steve, true.  A long would work...but what if that overflows.  The best answer is to use an algorithm that doesn't run that risk.

Comment: @Justin: Avoiding overflow doesn't require changing the *algorithm*, just the datatype. Assuming that `double` is the correct datatype to use for the sum, your answer does extra work (perhaps introducing extra inaccuracy), that's completely unrelated to avoiding overflow. Using a running average doesn't help avoid overflow in any way.

Comment: @Steve, if you assume that 'a large number of numbers' can be in the billions or trillions, then you can easily overflow the datatypes.  Or performance will die if using BigInt.

Comment: @Justin: OK, so go ahead and avoid `long` overflow, in which case double vs. BigInteger depends whether you need an accurate result or not. Either way, taking a running average is wrong.

Comment: Floating point won't be slower.  For a large number of integers, this will be limited by memory bandwidth anyway.

Comment: @Steve, Alas, I have given up.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your suggestions. Having read all the answers and comments, I'll continue with _long_ for now :)

Comment: any float point operation is just slow compared to integer ones and worst of all the loss of precision will so horrid that the end result won't resemble anything similar to avg.

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson: look at the solution below. It has close to zero overhead and it doesn't use BigInteger.

Comment: @bestsss, you are correct.  The only problem is if he overflows `long`.

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson - it's not possible, since w/ Integer.MAX_VALUE adds per long there is no way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use long (64-bit) to hold the sum. If you overrun that, BigInteger is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I was editing my question and meanwhile your answer came up. :) Actually I was wondering that can the algorithm be somehow optimized instead of just finding a way to store bigger sum.

Comment: Why are you assuming that sum followed by divide isn't the most optimal solution? Storing the intermediary result is going to be nothing even if you are dealing with gazillion integers. The sum just doesn't grow that fast. Adding and division are pretty basic operations and perform very fast.

Comment: Using long is the way to go, unless long is not long enough. With more than 2**32 numbers it could overflow. In such a case I'd recommend BigInteger. Using double could be faster in theory, but with so many numbers you most probably need to fetch it from the disk, which is way slower than any such computation. Don't care about the speed, it's surely useless optimization.

Comment: @maaartinus 2**32 integers is over 16GB of space. Can't belive that Asker need to calculate average of so many numbers. Also summing 2**32 BigInts will take forever :).

Comment: I know... but 16 GB is a tiny fraction of my HD and your "forever" takes less than 4 minutes. Still, it's much more than adding 2**32 longs.

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik: mod on x86_64 or whatever takes like 30 cycles (for instance). there is some solution that work properly for any arbitrary long sequences.

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik, A running average will NOT give you the same value as sum/count as it gives more weight to later numbers.

Answer (score 5):

BigInt is pretty fast. As I always say, **do it right first, profile and optimize later.**

Comment: "Do it right first" - that includes using the proper algorithm for the job.  See my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796433/what-should-be-the-most-optimal-way-to-find-the-average-of-large-number-of-intege/4796520#4796520

Comment: Pretty fast means order of magnitude slower than int. However, the memory latency probably dominates the computation time, anyway.

Comment: @Andrew, I'll give you that.  But, there is a specific algorithm suited perfectly for this purpose.  I'd say using that is the right way.

Comment: There is no need to use BigInt. I will work much slower compared with long(64 bit), which is enought for storing sum.

Answer (score 4):

How about `long` datatype?  It should be pretty fast even on 32-bit machines.

Comment: `long` will be big enough for around 4 billion worst-case ints. It's also *very* fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use floats and then convert the result back into a integer. That might not be optimal but should be fast enough (and straight forward)

Comment: That may also be incorrect in some cases, no (say, as an example, when suming up Integer.Max_VALUE-2 with Integer.Max_VALUE-3) ?

Comment: yes indeed, but I'm not sure you need a such precision for an average. Anyway the result is not a integer either but MAX_VALUE-2.5 .

Comment: Using float is pure nonsense given the existence of long and double. This way you get a wrong result even for averaging a single number, as e.g. `(int) (float) x != x` for `x=Integer.MAX_VALUE-1`.

Comment: ok. I m not a java expert so when I say floats I mean any floating type, and so double if needed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of ints you'll have to average in advance, you can do the division one-by-one

```
int [] a;
int average;
int remainder;
int alen = a.length;

for( int i = 0; i < alen; i++ ) {
  int q = a[i] / alen;  //calculate the quotient and the remainder for the current element
  int r = a[i] % alen;
  average += q; // add up the averages and the remainders
  remainder += r;
  if( remainder >= alen ) { //roll the average over if needed 
    remainder -= alen;
    average++;
  }
}
```

Of course in practice it doesn't matter because you can't have more than 2<sup>31</sup> elements in an array, which means you could store the sum in a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're calculating the average of billions of numbers, using BigInteger shouldn't have much of an effect on performance. You should try coding it with BigInteger and then decide if it's fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can store above 2billions of ints in a long. What's the problem?
Well, if you need even more ints. Do a simple class holding multiple longs (and long[] will do), and add on top of the 1st. Each 2billions of adds, get a fresh new long.

In the end (avg) sum the longs in a BigInteger and divide. The code has close to no overhead, one extra counter and one extra check (that's branch predicted).

[hopefully I didn't make some stupid off by 1 ;) ]

```
package t1;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Avg {
    long sum;
    long[] totals = new long[0];

    int counter;

    public void add(int v){
        if (counter++==Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            counter = 0;
            int len =totals.length;
            totals = Arrays.copyOf(totals, len+1);
            totals[len]=sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
        sum+=v;         
    }

    public int avg(){
        long count = this.counter;
        count+=totals.length*(long)Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(this.sum);
        for (long subSum : totals)
            sum=sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(subSum));

        return sum.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(count)).intValue();//tweak if you need be
    }
}
```